# Get Dynamic Background Color, Apply to Separate Element Using LESS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, glyphicons

There many discussions here about dynamic updating of color using LESS, e.g.: [dynamically change LESS variables in page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453506/dynamically-change-less-variables-in-page-with-javascript). But I have yet to see something that specifically addresses my challenge.

Our firm provides web software that gives users wide flexibility over the UI, including overall background color. But there are a number of elements that they can't change that need to have a background color in order to provide the proper user experience (cf. my Bootstrap Glyphicon question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926615/filling-in-hollow-area-only-for-bootstrap-glyphicon) -- sure would welcome an answer there, as well). I want to find a solution that takes whatever the user sets as a background color at any given time and applies it to other elements dynamically. I could do this via Javascript, but it seems like I should be able to leverage our use of LESS in our application stack to effectively create an unset mixin that is dynamically updated based on the user's UI choices. I tried many attempts to formularize a LESS solution, to no avail.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Before I go the JS route, I'd like to see if anyone can suggest a LESS-based solution for this challenge. As always, thanks in advance for any help you could provide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not usually use LESS in the browser, but going by the documentation provided [here](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/usage/using-less-in-the-browser.md) you can link to the javascript file that compiles your less files as

```
<!-- Here: include any less plugin scripts, any required browser shims and optionally set less = any options  -->
<script src="less.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<link data-dump-line-numbers="all" data-global-vars='{ "myvar": "#ddffee", "mystr": "\"quoted\"" }' rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/styles.less">
```

An even better approach would be to have configuration driven css generator, that generates the CSS file based on a set of parameters and gets served through a CDN.

Answer (score 1):

just use variables in less, but you will need to transpile in the browser or have the server re transpile the css on variable change